# SqlDependency.OnChange fires on one database but not another on the same server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to make a C# Forms program that views data from a database. It needs to request data on startup, cache it, then update it if the DB is updated. I'm trying to do it using SqlDependency. Here's the code:

```cs
    private const string connectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-VT1F04F\\MSSQLSERVER14;Initial Catalog=test1;Trusted_Connection=True";
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString);
        SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);
        ExecuteWatchingQuery();
    }
    private void ExecuteWatchingQuery()
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var command = new SqlCommand("select nbase, name from dbo.filial", connection);
            var sqlDependency = new SqlDependency(command);
            sqlDependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDatabaseChange);
            command.ExecuteReader();
        }
    }
    private void OnDatabaseChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs args)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("?");
        SqlNotificationInfo info = args.Info;
        if (SqlNotificationInfo.Insert.Equals(info)
            || SqlNotificationInfo.Update.Equals(info)
            || SqlNotificationInfo.Delete.Equals(info))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("!");
            //todo
        }
        ExecuteWatchingQuery();
    }
```

It doesn't do anything. `ExecuteWatchingQuery` competes fully, but `OnDatabaseChange` never fires. However, if I replace database test1 with a freshly created database watcher_test with a freshly created table, it works as intended. I have tried the following SQL commands:

```sql
alter database test1 set enable_broker
CREATE QUEUE ContactChangeMessages;  
CREATE SERVICE ContactChangeNotifications ON QUEUE ContactChangeMessages
```

Both databases have the same owner (as `select name, suser_sname(owner_sid) from sys.databases` shows), same permissions, they're on the same server, and I can't see any difference between them, in settings, or anywhere else. The program isn't able to access any table in the first database, but is able to access a copy of a table done with `insert into` from the first into the second table. The program behaves identically on a different computer that uses the same database restored from a backup.

Comment: Have you tried specifing the queue name `SqlDependency.Start(connectionString, "ContactChangeMessages");` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.start#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlDependency_Start_System_String_System_String_

Comment: Both databases don't work with that setting.

Comment: Did you also try to specify `ContactChangeNotifications` - don't know what string it should take, first time I heard about `SqlDependency` so I am just guessing - also found this maybe it helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758976/enabling-service-broker-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: That doesn't help either.