# C# SqlDependency equivalent in PHP 7.4.29 and SQL SERVER 2012

Tags: php-7.4, sqldependency

I couldn't find any resources on google and don't know where to start. Is there a PHP equivalent of C# SQLDependency? Where do I get it?
I have followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4778907/3103982) to enable service broker

> ALTER DATABASE [DBNAME] SET ENABLE_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

Thanks in advance